# How to examine and edit google-chrome Local Data?

Tags: google-chrome, local-storage

How does google-chrome store its Local Data?

Specifically, I'd like to have a command-line script that would display, or make a few specific changes to, some of the browser's local data.

I'm not asking how to write the software, but assuming there isn't already such a tool, I do need to know the specific files and their format.

I see that `.config/google-chrome/Default/Cookies` is an SQLite database, but I'm interested in `Default/Local Storage/leveldb/*.ldb`, I think.

(In case it makes any difference, assume Ubuntu 18.04.)

Comment: Will be a sort of helpful article :https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/storage/localstorage and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9404813/how-to-view-or-edit-localstorage

Comment: @user52599, thanks, but those articles describe how to access the data using a GUI.  What I want is something that can be run from the command line or from within a shell script.

Answer (score -1):

The user's data should not be accessed, it is what is said ethically. And that's what browser owners assume, although the data could be saved with a user password and a common encryption method, or using a PGP method. It would be a more transparent policy.

But if you are the user, you can partially solve your problem: 1. you can block cookies, block online work, IndexedDB, etc., and 2. follow this scheme: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Bc3HEEWBh9jh-GLvBPJFIDSb-UrmQi3l.

My solution is better than sharing a link to this question via email, Twitter, or Facebook, right? :)

---